# Convert Coordinate Notation tool

Tags: coordinate-system, convert

I am having trouble using the CCN tool.

My data is a DMS 442315 1214598 and I need to be in DD to work with my county data which I know is in the correct format.

I tried adding a new field then calculating it by using the string

```
left([Lat], 2) &""& right ([Lat], 2)
```

etc.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [tour] which is a gentle introduction to how to use this site, and provides a lead into its [help/on-topic].

Comment: Could you add more information? For example, which software are you using? How are the coordinates stored (text, table, shapefile)? There many different tools to achieve this task, and it is a lot easier to explain in whatever software platform you are using than trying to cover all possibilities.